# Why does this code have this error: "Expected:)"?

Tags: python, django, aptana

I am getting an error from Aptana "Expected:)" on this code at the `return render_to_response` line after the final `else:`.  I can't for the life of me figure out why that is, because as far as I can tell I have closed all of my parentheses.  I'm guessing that it is actually some other error and Aptana (Eclipse branch) is just not smart enough to give me the actual error.  When I attempt to load a webpage using another view in this file, it tells me only that it is a Syntax Error.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'Post':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                #return a 'disabled account' error message
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/disabled_account/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', {
                                         'failed_login' : True,
                                         'form' : AuthenticationForm()
                                                    },
                                        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                                     )
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html' {
                                        'failed_login' : False,
                                        'form' : AuthenticationForm()
                                                    },
                                        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                                     )
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? You should take hints from the interpreter, not the IDE.

Comment: I don't know python, but it seems you are missing `,` after `login.html` in `else` part. Check it :)

Comment: @Rafe, as I said, it simply tells me that there is a Syntax Error.

Comment: Just to clarify, a ")" was expected. Because the comma was missing, the IDE thought you'd had forgotten to close the function's parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the template name in the final return line.
You have:

```
return render_to_response('login.html' {
                                    'failed_login' : False,
                                    'form' : AuthenticationForm()
                                                },
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                                 )
```

But it should be:

```
return render_to_response('login.html', {
                                    'failed_login' : False,
                                    'form' : AuthenticationForm()
                                                },
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                                 )
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a comma missing after 'login.html' in the else: section